# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to retrieve form data, and came across a strange error...

```
dd($request->user_account);
```

returns

```
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "Elinor Pacocha"
  "email" => "justice.williamson@example.net"
  "password" => "tRVWNY9I59"
]
```

now i want to get the 'name' property:

```
dd($request->user_account->name);
```

This returns the following error:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

But it is working when i use:

```
dd($request->user_account['name']);
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

And the error is self-explanatory. Based on your response you get an array, so instead of accessing the property as of an object try it from the array like this:

```
dd($request->user_account['name']);
```

An object and an array is different. [Here](https://www.learn-php.org/en/Objects) a good tutorial to understand the object. And [here](https://www.learn-php.org/en/Simple_arrays) for arrays.